# How to answer how long you have been at your current job?

Tags: paperwork, express-entry

I am working on my online application for permanent residency in Canada from the US via Express Entry, and I'm being asked how long I have been at my current job. The form only has a pulldown menu to pick between and there is no other option to enter an alternate response. The question is "How long have you been employed at your current job" and the answers that possibly apply to me are "1-2 years," and "3+" years." I have been at my job for 2 years and a few months, which doesn't seem to fit into either of those two choices.

When it comes to indicating how long you've been with a company, how do you address rounding the years like this? Since I have been here for more than 2 years do I immediately go up to the next tier? Or since I have not been here for a FULL 3 years, do I not yet qualify for the 3+ years?

I originally posted this in the Workplace exchange and was told it was off-topic. Perhaps someone here has knowledge on this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also hate forms that are designed to only consider integer answers for this type of question. But we have to deal with them.

In this case, I would strongly recommend that you choose the "1-2 years" option. Given the way they have chosen to phrase the options, it's clear that this choice means either "1 year and some months we don't care about" or "2 years and some months we don't care about". You fit into the latter category.

More importantly, you certainly have not been at your job for more than 3 years, and a good rule of thumb with every immigration authority is never to provide an answer that might be interpreted as deceptive.

[Re: points question below]

I do not have specific experience with Canada's express entry program. The 1st link below suggests that you can only update your profile if you are found eligible for the pool. The 2nd link suggests that eligible applicants stay in the pool for 12 months and that your consideration for permanent residence is based on the CRS points you score. Worst case scenario: you reapply in 12 months time with a higher CRS score.

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1005&top=29

https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/works.html

Comment: Probably a good idea to play it safe, although this would mean a difference of 25 points on my express entry application. Are you able to update an application once it's been submitted? For instance, if my 3-year anniversary at work occurs in 3 months, can I submit the application as saying I've been there 1-2 years, and then in 3 months update it to 3+ years?

Comment: I do not have specific experience with Canada's express entry program. The first link below suggests that you can only update your profile if you are found eligible for the pool.http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1005&top=29